# Cadastrando dados com laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Não consigo retornar o usuário para uma determinada página após o cadastramento de um formulário de cadastro, os dados vão para o banco normalmente, mas retorna um erro.

Minha classe de `Controller`

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{

    public function newAccount(UserSystem $user, NewAccountRequest $account)
    {

         $user->create([

            $user->first_name = $account->get('first_name'),
            $user->last_name = $account->get('last_name'),
            $user->email = $account->get('email'),
            $user->username = $account->get('username'),
            $user->secret = bcrypt($account->get('secret')),
            $result = $user->save()
        ]);


        ($result) ? 
        redirect()->route('login')->with('Conta criada com sucesso') :
        redirect()->route('new-account')->with('Houve uma falha ao criar a conta');

    }

}
```

*Model*

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserSystem extends Model
{
    //
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
    protected $table = 'user_systems';

}
```

e me retorna esse erro:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `user_systems` (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (testando, teste@teste.com, teste1, $2y$10$3.LTta6El5nckmTNBRYBa.tyS.ho0ObpAwSVNSyZLMfMSqSwPNEwy, 2019-09-16 12:58:08, 2019-09-16 12:58:08))
```

E na documentação do [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) diz:

> Você também pode usar o create método para salvar um novo modelo em
>   uma única linha. A instância do modelo inserido será retornada a você
>   a partir do método No entanto, antes de fazer isso, você precisará
>   especificar um fillableou um guardedatributo no modelo, pois todos os
>   modelos Eloquent protegem contra a atribuição em massa por padrão.
>
> Uma vulnerabilidade de atribuição em massa ocorre quando um usuário
>   passa um parâmetro HTTP inesperado por meio de uma solicitação e esse
>   parâmetro altera uma coluna em seu banco de dados que você não
>   esperava. Por exemplo, um usuário mal-intencionado pode enviar um
>   is_adminparâmetro por meio de uma solicitação HTTP, que é passada ao
>   createmétodo do seu modelo , permitindo que o usuário se encaminhar
>   para um administrador.
>
> Portanto, para começar, defina quais atributos do modelo você deseja
>   atribuir em massa. Você pode fazer isso usando a $fillablepropriedade
>   no modelo. Por exemplo, vamos nameatribuir o atributo de nossa
>   Flightmassa de modelo:

Como faço para passar esses valores que eu peguei para o banco sem dar esse erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Utilizando o método save() no model.**

```
public function newAccount( NewAccountRequest $account)
{

$user = new UserSystem;

$user->first_name = $account->get('first_name');
$user->last_name = $account->get('last_name');
$user->email = $account->get('email');
$user->username = $account->get('username');
$user->secret = bcrypt($account->get('secret'));
$result = $user->save();


($result) ?
redirect()->route('login')->with('Conta criada com sucesso') :
redirect()->route('new-account')->with('Houve uma falha ao criar a conta');

}

}
```

**Utilizando o método create() no model.**

class AccountController extends Controller
{

```
public function newAccount( NewAccountRequest $account)
{
    $result= UserSystem::create([
    'first_name' => $account->get('first_name'),
    'last_name' => $account->get('last_name'),
    'email' => $account->get('email'),
    'username' => $account->get('username'),
    'secret' => bcrypt($account->get('secret')),
    ];


    ($result) ?
    redirect()->route('login')->with('Conta criada com sucesso') :
    redirect()->route('new-account')->with('Houve uma falha ao criar a conta');

}
```

}

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserSystem extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'secret'];


//protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'user_systems';

}
```

Comment: Eu dei uma lida sobre MVC e me surgiu outra dúvida que não entendi ao certo. O correto é aplicar os métodos CRUD no controller ou na própria Model? E a validação vai junto com esses dados ou deve-ser tratada de uma maneira isolada e depois passada apenas para cadastrar?

Comment: Sobre os atributos `$fillable` e `$guarded` não chegam a estarem errados? De acordo com a documentação do Laravel deve-se usar um ou outro, mas não ambos como citado: "A instância do modelo inserido será retornada a você a partir do método No entanto, antes de fazer isso, você precisará especificar um fillable ou um guarded atributo no modelo, pois todos os modelos Eloquent protegem contra a atribuição em massa por padrão."

Comment: Há argumentos para todos os gostos, pode fazer tudo no controlador e não há nada de errado. Contudo existem boas práticas e o laravel fornece muitas ferramentas, como por exemplo validação no request. Deve ler a documentação e existem milhares de tutoriais on-line

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queira manter a sua inserção com create, como você colocou no seu exemplo, você passa um array de objetos, então vc faz o seguinte:

**Ao invés disso:**

```
$user->create([

            $user->first_name = $account->get('first_name'),
            $user->last_name = $account->get('last_name'),
            $user->email = $account->get('email'),
            $user->username = $account->get('username'),
            $user->secret = bcrypt($account->get('secret')),
            $result = $user->save()
        ]);
```

**Faça isso:**

```
$user = App\User::updateOrCreate([
            'first_name' => $account->get('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $account->get('last_name'),
            'email' => $account->get('email'),
            'username' => $account->get('username'),
            'secret' => bcrypt($account->get('secret')),
        ]);
```